# $http.get Authorization Angular Error

Tags: angularjs, http

Envia la peticion siempre y cuando lo hago sin el header, una vez que pongo el header me sale error

```
getMark : function(){
            var tokenId = 'tok ' + sesionesControl.get('token');
            //tokenId me regresa el token registrado...

            var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Authorization': tokenId
                }
            };

            $http.get('http://sitio.com/app/user',config)
                .success(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                })
                .error(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                });
        }
```

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://sitio.com/app/user. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
>   The response had HTTP status code 404.

```
OPTIONS /app/user HTTP/1.1
Host: sitio.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.84 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost/Angular/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

Gracias a los que respondan :)

P.D. Al enviar usando aplicaciones(extensiones de Chrome) como PostMan si reconoce

Comment: tienes activado CORS en el servidor?

Comment: Esto es un problema de configuración del servidor. Recuerda que CORS es un mecanismo de seguridad del navegador y Postman no es un navegador, por eso te funciona en ese caso.

Comment: El problema no está en el token de autenticación sino en la configuración del CORS. [Aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) hay una excelente explicación de como funciona. Espero que sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta del lado del servidor, habilita el CORS para que te permite usarlo.

Como extra cambia .succes y .error, por .then y .catch, los anteriores ya esta depreciados.